# setInterval refreshes the app instead of updating the state

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, expo, setinterval

I'm coding a countdown with `Expo`. 
I'm using `functional components`, so my `state` is handled via React's `useState` hook.

```
let [state, setState] = useState({
    secondsLeft: 25,
    started: false,
});
```

If I press a `Button` it does fire this function:

```
let onPressHandler = (): void => {
    if(!state.started) {
        setState({...state, started: true});
        setInterval(()=> {
            setState({...state, secondsLeft: state.secondsLeft - 1});
            console.log(state.secondsLeft);
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Problem is that **each 1000 ms Expo refreshes the app instead of updating the state.**

[image]

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It updates the state, but it uses stale state to do so. The `state` variable in your `setInterval` callback will never change once the interval is started.

Instead, use the setter form of the state update function, so you're always working with the then-current state:

```
let onPressHandler = (): void => {
    if(!state.started) {
        setState({...state, started: true});
        setInterval(()=> {
            setState(currentState => {
                const newState = {...currentState, secondsLeft: currentState.secondsLeft - 1};
                console.log(newState.secondsLeft);
                return newState;
            });
        }, 1000);
    }
};
```

It's more concise without the `console.log`:

```
let onPressHandler = (): void => {
    if(!state.started) {
        setState({...state, started: true});
        setInterval(()=> {
            setState(currentState => {...currentState, secondsLeft: currentState.secondsLeft - 1});
        }, 1000);
    }
};
```

---

On a separate note: If you have state items that you update independently from one another, best practice is to use separate state variables for them. Also, since they're constant within your function, it's best to declare them as `const`. Like this:

```
const [secondsLeft, setSecondsLeft] = useState(25);
const [started, setStarted] = useState(false);

// ...
let onPressHandler = (): void => {
    if(!started) {
        setStarted(true);
        setInterval(()=> {
            setSecondsLeft(seconds => seconds - 1);
        }, 1000);
    }
};
```

Also, since you can't rely on `setInterval` to be at all precise, I suggest storing your stop time ("now" plus 25 seconds) and recalculating how many seconds are left each time:

```
let onPressHandler = (): void => {
    const stopTime = Date.now() + (DURATION * 1000);
    setStarted(true);
    setSecondsLeft(DURATION);
    const timer = setInterval(()=> {
        const left = Math.round((stopTime - Date.now()) / 1000);
        if (left <= 0) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            setStarted(false);
        } else {
            setSecondsLeft(left);
        }
    }, 1000);
};
```

Live Example (with logic for stopping):

```js
const {useState} = React;

const Example = () => {
    const DURATION = 25; // seconds
    const [started, setStarted] = useState(false);
    const [secondsLeft, setSecondsLeft] = useState(0);

    if (started) {
        return <div>Seconds left: {secondsLeft}</div>;
    }

    let onPressHandler = ()/*: void*/ => {
        const stopTime = Date.now() + (DURATION * 1000);
        setStarted(true);
        setSecondsLeft(DURATION);
        const timer = setInterval(()=> {
            const left = Math.round((stopTime - Date.now()) / 1000);
            if (left <= 0) {
                clearInterval(timer);
                setStarted(false);
            } else {
                setSecondsLeft(left);
            }
        }, 1000);
    };
    return (
        <input
            type="button"
            onClick={onPressHandler}
            value="Start"
        />
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your very clear and exhaustive explanation!